# Search bar no content is returned

Tags: python, html, django, search, django-views

Hey i am new to Django and I am trying to make a search bar to my first site.
My problem here is when I search for any value that I/user entered and on the site, the site only refreshes and doesn't give me anything back but the empty option that i gave the site to display when there is no content to match the search.

(That's not all of the Topic model)

**model.py**

```
class Topic(models.Model):

    content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        result = Topic.objects.filter(content__icontains=query)
        context = { 'query': query, 'result': result}
        return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

(that's all of the topics.html i am sorry of how it turned this not what it really looks like on the original topics.html but that's the full topics.html )

**topics.html**

```
% extends "leaning_logs\base.html" %}
    
{% block page_header %}
    <h1>Topics </h1>
    <br><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}">Add a new topic</a></br>
{% endblock page_header %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'learning_logs:search' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" placeholder="search..">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
            Search</button>
    </form>

        {% for topic in topics %}
            <div class="card-mb3">
                <div class="card-header" style="background-color:lightgrey">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Title of the topic</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                            <div class="card-body" style="background- color:white">
                               <tr>
                                  <td>
                                    {% if topic.image %}
                                <image src="{{topic.image.url}}" style="width:200px">
                            {% else %}
                                <span class="text-muted">No Image have been added</span>
                            {% endif %}
                        <td><h3>
                            <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}" style="float:center">{{topic}}</a>
                        </td></h3>
                                
                        <td><small><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_topic' topic.id %}">
                        <button method="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Edit topic</button></a></small></td>
                            
                        <td><small><form method="post" action="{% url 'learning_logs:delete_topic' topic.id %}">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-primary" >
                        Delete topic</button></form></small></td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% empty %}
            <h3><li>No topics have been added yet.</li></h3>
            
        {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: We definitely need to see all of topics.html to help you.

Comment: okay done and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

`{% for topic in topics %}`

should be that:

`{% for topic in result %}`